# ListCtrl set string item

Tags: python, list, wxpython

I have an array of strings say `['Hello World', 'Goodbye Universe', Let's go to the mall']` and i want to put in a ListCtrl how ever my code only prints out certain letters of each index in the array.
My code :

```
self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel,size=(1000,1000))
self.list.InsertColumn(0,'Rules')
for i in actualrules:
    self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i[0])
```

actualrules is the array

Comment: Variable `i` seems to be a string, not an index. You should get some errors (coming from `actualrules[i]`), is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list actualrules has a single quote in one of the strings so you should surround it with double quotes as shown below.

```
        actualrules = ['Hello World', 'Goodbye Universe',
                   "Let's go to the mall"]
```

In your for loop i becomes each item of the list then you are taking only the first letter by doing i[0]

Below is a working example of your list

```
import sys
import wx


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        actualrules = ['Hello World', 'Goodbye Universe',
                       "Let's go to the mall"]

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(1000, 1000), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Rules')
        for i in actualrules:
            self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i)

        pSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pSizer.Add(self.list, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(pSizer)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vSizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(False)
    testFrame = TestFrame(None)
    testFrame.Show()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```